# 'Internal Server Error' in Magento multistore (subdomain)

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, frontend-error

I'm running Magento CE 1.8. I've set up multiple stores (website, store, and store view) in Magento successfully using parked domains. Yesterday, I set up two additional stores using subdomains. Here's what I followed...
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento-multistore.htm
The only thing I did differently was adding the code to index.php. Adding the code this article indicates causes an error, since the index.php already has the following code:

> /* Store or website code */
>   $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : ' ';
>
> /* Run store or run website */ $mageRunType =
>   isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] :
>   'store';

So, I just filled it in with the right info.

The homepage of each new store works fine. But that's it. If I try to navigate to my cart, a product page, or CMS page, I get an internal server error, with a notice that a 500 error occured when trying to use an error handler. It's not putting out error logs on the server, so it's hard to know what's not working. The root install of Magento, as well as the additional stores I had already set up using parked domains still funtion fine on all pages, including the admin.

I've checked memory limits in my .htaccess file, and it's set to 256m. I think that's good enough; I don't have a whole lot of SKUs running in any of my stores.

Any help is greatly appreciated - I have to get these stores up ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the log_errors and error_log directives to configure PHP error logging via .htaccess.

```
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /path/filename
```

Comment: I dropped the code into the end of my .htaccess, but i gave me a 500 Error when trying to load the site, and didn't output an error file...

Comment: To display php errors on frontend:
`php_flag display_startup_errors on`
`php_flag display_errors on`
`php_flag html_errors on`

And check Apache log file, probably webserver cannot read/write changed files (index.php, .htaccess, /path/filename)

Comment: I'm on a shared server, and can't access Apache server logs. But I'll try that in my .htaccess file to display errors on the front end.

Comment: I tried that code; didn't work. Thanks though.